# How to identify an application executable from ps

Tags: bash, process

If I execute

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

I get the following

```
noaccess 12144   908   0   Apr 28 ?         697:47 /usr/java/bin/java -server -Xmx128m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
```

Though, in this server we have many Java applications running. How do I identify which .jar was invoked by the ps output is showing?

Comment: You should re-evaluate the way you launch your applications.  Eclipse and Aptana both report the launched jar properly.

Comment: Parsing `ps` is always unreliable. You should have one process that runs them all, and keeps control over them. See [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: sometimes you don't have much control on how you start your third-party server (e.g. Hudson, Nexus). When one hang unexpectedly and has to be killed, how do you identify which one is which from the ps command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try lsof. For example,

```
lsof -a -p 12144 -u noaccess | grep REG
```

which would list the regular files that process/user has open.

From the result you might be able to determine which java process is which.